# Django create bounded form with ManyToMany Field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create bounded form with ManytoMany field

i have my models.py like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'message_sender')
    user_receiver = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'message_receiver', null = True, blank = True)
    group_receiver = models.ManyToManyField(Group, null = True, blank = True)
    message_content = models.TextField()
    send_time = models.DateTimeField('Scheduled Date & Time',null = True, blank = True)
    MESSAGE_STATUS = (('OUTBOX','Outbox'),('SEND','Send'),('SEEN','Received'))
    status=models.CharField(max_length = 6, choices = MESSAGE_STATUS)
```

my views.py

```
def edit_message(request, message_id):
e_message=Message.objects.get(id=message_id)
data={'user_receivers':e_message.user_receiver,
    'group_receivers':e_message.group_receiver,
    'message':e_message.message_content,
    'scheduled_time':e_message.send_time
}
form=ComposeMessageForm(data)
context = {'form':form}
return render(request,'msgin/compose_message.html',context)
```

I get the error saying

```
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

How can i make a bounded form with ManytoMany field

i want to do something like this ie replacing e_message.user_receiver...

```
def edit_message(request, message_id):
e_message=Message.objects.get(id=message_id)
data={'user_receivers':[u'1',u'2'],
    'group_receivers':e_message.group_receiver,
    'message':e_message.message_content,
    'scheduled_time':e_message.send_time
}
form=ComposeMessageForm(data)
context = {'form':form}
return render(request,'msgin/compose_message.html',context)
```

here the given list is previously selected users of that particular message_id

Comment: how can i change the e_message.user_receiver object in the form of list like     [u'1', u'6']

Answer (score 0):

You forget the `all()`:

```
data = {
    'user_receivers': e_message.user_receiver,
    'group_receivers': e_message.group_receiver.all(),
    'message': e_message.message_content.all(),
    'scheduled_time': e_message.send_time
}
```

Comment: this will give me all the existing user and group          i want to edit the already saved m2m data... thus i need to represent the data in the form of list like  [u'1', u'6']   ...

Comment: First, I have no idea what `[u'1', u'6']` means. Second, why do you think `e_message.group_receiver.all()` will output **all** existing users?

Comment: i have already saved the the message object with many to many field.....i want to edit the previously selected m2m field of that message object... so i need to bound the form with previously selected user_receiver and group_receiver

Comment: @wrufesh What is `previously selected user_receiver` anyway?

Comment: user_receiver is in ManyToMany relation with User class...and i have saved a message with user_receiver in m2m relation with some User.. ijust want to edit it

Comment: @wrufesh If I understand you correctly, you want to get `User`s who received your `Message` of `message_id`, right? Then `all()` just does what you want.